# Code coverage and Profiling command line tool in VS2010 Ultimate

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, profiling, code-coverage

I can run those commands to generate the .coverage file to get the code coverage result.

```
vsinstr -coverage helloclass.exe /exclude:std::*
vsperfcmd /start:coverage /output:run.coverage
helloclass
vsperfcmd /shutdown
```

Can I use the same tool for getting profiling report?

- If so, what can I do that?
- If not, what tools are available for profiling in VS2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Profiling uses the same toolset as code coverage, but the commands are slightly different.  With profiling, you can do both instrumentation and sample profiling.

For instrumentation profiling (the most similar to code coverage):

```
vsinstr myapp.exe
vsperfcmd /start:trace /output:trace.vsp
myapp
vsperfcmd /shutdown
```

For sample profiling (sampling):

```
vsperfcmd /start:sample /output:sample.vsp /launch:myapp.exe
vsperfcmd /shutdown
```

These steps change slightly if you're profiling managed code (you would also need to use `vsperfclrenv`).  MSDN has good documentation and examples on using the [profiling command-line tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182401%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @prosseek: the preferred method is to open it directly in Visual Studio (File » Open). For command-line textual reporting, see `VSPerfReport.exe`, e.g. `vsperfreport /summary:all foo.vsp`.